# QuickSort non recursive with stack python

Tags: python

i've got this code:

```
class Pila () : 
  inferior=0 
  superior=0

  lista = [8,5,6,4,3,2,10]


def quicksortNoRec (lista) : 
    """Ordena la lista siguiendo el algoritmo quicksort 
       o de ordenacin rapida. Forma no recursiva""" 
    qs(lista,0,len(lista)-1)
    return lista 

def qs (lista,inicial,final) : 
  p=1 
  "declaramos la pila de estructuras" 
  pila=[20] 
  for m in range(0,20) : 
    pila=Pila() 
  "ahora se comienza a ordenar" 
  pila[p].inferior,pila[p].superior=inicial,final 
  while p : 
    inicial,final=pila[p].inferior,pila[p].superior 
    p-=1 
    izdo,dcho=inferior,superior 
    while inferior<dcho : 
      izdo,dcho=inferior,superior 
      mitad=lista[izdo+((dcho-izdo)/2)] 
      while izdo<=dcho : 
        while lista[izdo]<mitad and izdo<final : izdo+=1 
        while mitad<lista[dcho] and dcho>inicial : dcho-=1 
        if izdo<=dcho : 
          lista[izdo],lista[dcho]=lista[dcho],lista[izdo] 
          izdo+=1 
          dcho-=1 
      if izdo<final : 
        p+=1 
        pila[p].inferior,pila[p].superior=izdo,final 
      final=dcho 
  return lista
```

I don't know where is the mistake, and i can't run it, could you help me?. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error message of any kind? What's it supposed to do?

Comment: it orders numbers without recursion and with stack, but im newbie in python, and i dont know how to run the code, and if i call the function qs, it shows me an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "name of file.py", line 42, in <module>
    print quicksortNoRec(lista)
NameError: name 'lista' is not defined

Comment: how are you calling it? you need to give it a list to sort try `print quickSortNoRec([5,10,20,1,2,3,55])`

Comment: ... and why don't tell it "the lista"? Like [1,2...

Comment: `[20]` means a list that contains 1 element and this element is `20`. you want `pila = []`

Comment: Also, be careful that you return original lista, not the result of qs

Comment: then, your loop to create pilas only affects the new Pilas to the same variable. Then, you call pila[p], with p being 1, which results in an error because pila is not a list, it is a Pila.

Comment: I try print quicksortNoRec like you told me, but it show me a error:

Comment: yeah thats because you have more problems than that.  that was just the first issue see my answer ... I think it will run if you do that ... no idea if it will do what you want it to

Comment: well new errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "namefile", line 40, in <module>
    print quicksortNoRec([5,10,20,1,2,3,55])
  File "namefile", line 9, in quicksortNoRec
    qs(lista,0,len(lista)-1)
  File "namefile", line 19, in qs
    pila[p].inferior,pila[p].superior=inicial,final
AttributeError: Pila instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pila () : 
  inferior=0 
  superior=0

  lista = [8,5,6,4,3,2,10]
```

I think you want lista definition outside of this class

```
class Pila () : 
  inferior=0 
  superior=0

lista = [8,5,6,4,3,2,10]
```

but thats only one of your problems ...

another problem is here

```
def qs (lista,inicial,final) : 
  p=1 
  "declaramos la pila de estructuras" 
  pila=[20] 
  for m in range(0,20) : 
    pila=Pila()
```

Im pretty sure you want

```
def qs (lista,inicial,final) : 
  p=1 
  "declaramos la pila de estructuras" 
  pila=[Pila()  for m in range(0,20)]
```

then I think it will at least run ... no idea if it will do what you expct though

Comment: nothing, it show a error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonpilas", line 37, in <module>
    print quicksortNoRec([5,10,20,1,2,3,55])
  File "pythonpilas", line 8, in quicksortNoRec
    qs(lista,0,len(lista)-1)
  File "pythonpilas", line 20, in qs
    izdo,dcho=inferior,superior
NameError: global name 'inferior' is not defined

Comment: oh ... hmmm im not sure what those values are supposed to be ... this code is really buggy ... where did you get it? why dont you just start from scratch ... or write it in pseudocode then translate it to python

Comment: how bout you do it in any language up to and including pseudo-code?